# Color first element that has attribute and it's not first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set a background color for the first element that:

1. has the attribute: `data-attr=false`
2. it's not the first child of his parent.

So if it's the first child, don't color it.
If it's not the first child, color only the first element that has `data-attr=false`.

**Examples:**

---

**1)**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

The second one should be colored.

---

**2)**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

No one should be colored (cause the first element that has `data-attr=false` is the first child of the div).

---

There is no case that the first element has `data-attr=false` and the second element has `data-attr=true`.

[**This is my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8skttbwu/)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a selector for the first element that matches an attribute selector.

However, since there will never be a case where the first element has `data-attr=false` and the second `data-attr=true`, assuming your container will only ever contain two `p` elements, matching your desired element remains fairly simple:

```css
p[data-attr=true] + p[data-attr=false] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry but it doesn't work for a case that there is an empty p..
here is example with li instead of p..

http://jsfiddle.net/28bjgsfg/

Comment: @Erez Shmiel: That seems like an awfully big omission... might wanna edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a new answer, just a little modified version of [@BoltClock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524700/2081719)*

To target more than one following paragraph with `data-attr="false"` in case first child paragraph has `data-attr="true"`, use this **`p[data-attr=true]:first-child ~ p[data-attr=false]`**

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/13ymb139/1/)

```css
p[data-attr=true]:first-child ~ p[data-attr=false] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The first paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph. False.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The third paragraph. False.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The first paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The second paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The third paragraph. False.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The first paragraph. False.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The second paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The third paragraph. False.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The first paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph. False.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=true>The third paragraph. True.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The forth paragraph. False.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The first paragraph. False.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The second paragraph. False.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" data-attr=false>The third paragraph. False.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry but it doesn't work for a case that there is an empty p.. here is example with li instead of p.. jsfiddle.net/28bjgsfg

Comment: I think it does work where there're empty children they get ignored since they don't have `data-attr`, try changing the first `li` `true` to `false`, or change any "non-first" `li` `false` to `true`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand.. It colors some li's that are false.. not only the first one..

Comment: you want it to color ***only the first*** `li` that has `data-attr=false` and not the first child? and if there's an empty `li` before it then the "`data-attr=false` should be colored or not?

Comment: also, will there always be empty li in between? if so, use this `li[data-attr=true]:first-child ~ li[data-attr=false]:nth-child(3)` [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygorou7x/)

Comment: if, there *might* be empty `li` or *might not*,  use a mix of BoltClock and my last rule, `li[data-attr=true] + li[data-attr=false], li[data-attr=true]:first-child ~ li[data-attr=false]:nth-child(3)` as in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygorou7x/1/)